Getting SamplerV2 run error when fitting VQC
I am exploring Quantum machine learning algorithms and I am following the Qiskit Machine Learning GitHub tutorial to train a variational quantum classifier (VQC). I am trying to run the VQC on a quantum computer as a backend, instead of using a simulator, however, I am encountering an issue when using the updated Qiskit Runtime V2 Sampler to do so.
This is the error I am receiving:
TypeError: SamplerV2.run() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

This is the code I am using, it is from the Qiskit Machine Learning GitHub page, except that I am specifying a sampler configured with IBM Quantum computer as a backend.
from qiskit.circuit.library import TwoLocal, ZZFeatureMap
from qiskit_algorithms.optimizers import COBYLA
from qiskit_algorithms.utils import algorithm_globals

from qiskit_machine_learning.algorithms import VQC
from qiskit_machine_learning.datasets import ad_hoc_data

seed = 1376
algorithm_globals.random_seed = seed

# Use ad hoc data set for training and test data
feature_dim = 2  # dimension of each data point
training_size = 20
test_size = 10

# training features, training labels, test features, test labels as np.ndarray,
# one hot encoding for labels
training_features, training_labels, test_features, test_labels = ad_hoc_data(
    training_size=training_size, test_size=test_size, n=feature_dim, gap=0.3
)

feature_map = ZZFeatureMap(feature_dimension=feature_dim, reps=2, entanglement="linear")
ansatz = TwoLocal(feature_map.num_qubits, ["ry", "rz"], "cz", reps=3)

# This is the code I am using to run the VQC on a quantum computer
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService, SamplerV2 as Sampler
service = QiskitRuntimeService(channel="ibm_cloud", token="<IBM Cloud API key>", instance="<IBM Cloud CRN>")
backend = service.least_busy(operational=True, simulator=False)
sampler = Sampler(backend = backend)

vqc = VQC(
    feature_map=feature_map,
    ansatz=ansatz,
    optimizer=COBYLA(maxiter=100),
    sampler=sampler
)
vqc.fit(training_features, training_labels)

I am using qiskit 1.1.0 and qiskit-ibm-runtime 0.22.0.
I have read through the IBM Quantum, Qiskit IBM runtime and Qiskit migration docs and tried searching for similar issues but could not find any information on this. I am relatively new to quantum computing and many tutorials and help pages are still referring to older primitives or obsolete qiskit packages, so not sure if there is something I am not understanding about the newer V2 primitives. Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you!

It seems that Qiskit Machine Learning module does not support V2 primitives yet. See here.

@Egretta.Thula Thanks for pointing me to this! The V1 primitives are also affected by the migration to V2 primitives and I haven't got them to work either, likely as they have been deprecated. On further research it appears that in the meantime, the only solution would be to use qiskit.primitives.BackendSampler. Either way, thank you for the help!

Update: seems like it is an ongoing issue, another workaround here: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ibm-runtime/issues/1718
